# Python logging sending logs to standard out

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I am running the following code in a custom Python application:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(filemode='example.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
```

but the output is being written to standard out. I ran the same code from a Jupyter notebook and it creates the example.log file and writes the log message to it.

I read that the order of imports may be important. Here is the order:

```
import logging
import argparse
import time
import os
import sys
import json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo in the arguments to [`basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig).

Instead of setting `filename` to `example.log`, you set `filemode`, which is something else!

It worked for me like this:

```
import logging

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
```

Comment: haha yup, just realized that as well. Wish there was a better way to have figured that out than just by skimming over the code over and over.